# Where are Shell Functions held?

Tags: bash, function

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer me on my question

Is there's a hash table where defined shell functions are kept?  If so, what is it called?

So basically I'm wondering where in a shell (BASH) functions are stored. I know I can use the declare command to view them, but I suspect there is a hash table for them... but I can't find any reference to a memory structure that specifically holds them.

If anyone could tell me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a hash table. See [the source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n112).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!